# only when qualities outweigh the dangers does

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion, fronting

I am confused when analysing the sentence below, especially the grammatical structure.

> He emphasized that only when the positive qualities outweigh the dangers does healthy psychosocial development take place.

I have these questions:

1. > I cannot justify the word **does** in the sentence.( Specially, its position )
2. > Why didn't the writer use a comma after **does** (to indicate a relative clause).

It must be noted that the sentence is taken from an academic text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, *does* is part of the main clause and **not** a part of the subclause. It is simply used to emphasize the verb phrase *take place*. Let me break it down for you:

> He emphasized that *only when the positive qualities outweigh the dangers* **does** healthy psychosocial development **take place**.

The part in italic is your subclause, while the other parts are your main clause. If you replace the subclause with a pronoun, this becomes more clear:

> He emphasized that *only then* does healthy psychosocial development take place.

So, you see that *does* is not a part of this subclause and is used simply to emphasize the main clause's verb. The verb *to do* is often used for emphasis:

> - He doesn't love you.
> - He **does** love me!

There are several different cases where the verb *to do* can be used for emphasis. Have a look at [this article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode119/languagepoint.shtml) to learn more.

---

About the placing of *does*:

The verb *does* here is placed before the subject because of **inversion**. After phrases with *only then, only when, only if etc.* the subject and auxiliary verb are normally inverted. Have a look at [this article on Grammaring](http://www.grammaring.com/only-after-only-if-only-in-this-way-etc-not-until).

Comment: Why we do not say:" when the positive qualities outweigh the dangers, healthy psychosocial development does take place". I knew about the emphasizing role of do,does,did. My question is why he did not put the does just before the verb take place ? and why he did not use coma ?

Comment: It's inversion that takes place after *only when* in initial position, I'll add it to my answer.